# PHP Paypal Automated Pages Issue

Tags: php, html, arrays, paypal

So right I am building an ecommerce site with PHP. We only have 1 product page that is linked to an array that has the name/price/image, so that it makes 9 product pages as the array has 9 products. We have a standard form that has a paypal button on the main product.php so it displays on every product page automatically. Here's my question, if I want to have a text box or another paypal button on one of these product pages, how do i do it? Do I have to restructure the site so that every product has it's own page?

can't post code as there's a lot of it and stackoverflow won't accept it even though I've indented it.

If it's confusing, better explanation: I have 2 php files. The main php file has an include file to an array, and the main php file has the paypal button form. The products php file has an array with 9 elements so there's 9 product pages. I want some of those product pages to be different from eachother in terms of the html, **so HOW do I put html that only applies to one element of an array?**

Thanks, Eliot

Comment: build only 1 product page, pass the element to it and construct data dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my best to help you, if i misunderstood you just let me know.

In terms of template files (the HTML files contains the Paypal button) you should have a main template file in each product that will include the templates for it (like the Paypal button form and other template according to conditions you can check in that main template).

For example if the product type is 'book' just add another template (a form with a button) to view the first page or whatever you like to do other than the Paypal button, 
so the result will be that all product will be the only the paypal buttonbut the books will have another button.